# Class Static Array field change value suddenly(C++)

Tags: c++

this is snippet of Block class :

```
class Block { public:
    //size satu blok(dalam byte)
    static const int BLOCK_SIZE = 4096;    

    Block(int number,byte *data):number(number) {        
       for(int i=0;i<BLOCK_SIZE;i++) {
           this->data[i] = data[i];         
       }    
    }

    void test();
     private:
    byte data[BLOCK_SIZE];    
    const int number; };
```

note that byte is just typedef unsigned char

and this is one of the function in other class that initialize block variable

```
bool Filesystem::getBlock(int number, Block *block) {        
    fstream fin(path);
    if(!fin.is_open() || number<0) {
        return false;
    }
    byte data[Block::BLOCK_SIZE];        
    fin.seekg(Block::BLOCK_SIZE*number,ios::beg);                       
    for(int i=0;i<Block::BLOCK_SIZE;i++) {
        fin>>data[i];                
    }
    block = new Block(number,data);    
    (*block).test();//this is the first test, this prints values as expected
    fin.close();
    return true;
}
```

this is another snippet :

```
Block *superblock;
getBlock(0,superblock);
(*superblock).test();//this is the second test, this prints random value
```

test is a function that prints the first four bytes from data in block
when i first use the test function inside the getblock, it prints exactly like i wanted(same as the file) but when i tried to print it the second time exactly after i call getblock, it prints random value

anyone knows where the mistake?

Comment: You can just do `block->test()` instead of `(*block).test()`.

Comment: A small suggestion: In the `Block` constructor, instead of copying the data one byte at a time in a loop, use the [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) function. It's optimized for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
block = new Block(number,data);
```

This line creates a new `Block` object and assigns it to the parameter `block`. However, the pointer `block` is passed into the function *by value*, so the original pointer `superblock` is not affected by this line. Hence, you are operating on different `Block`-objects inside and outside of your function.

To solve this problem, you can use a reference to a pointer as your parameter:

```
bool Filesystem::getBlock(int number, Block *&block);
```

Comment: hmm i got Filesystem.h:28:38: error: cannot declare pointer to ‘class Block&’
Filesystem.cpp:68:47: error: cannot declare pointer to ‘class Block&’

Comment: i realized it but late to comment. thx very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of mistakes are on this line:

```
fstream fin(path);
```

And on these lines:

```
for(int i=0;i<Block::BLOCK_SIZE;i++) {
    fin>>data[i];                
}
```

The first line is wrong because you have to open the file in binary mode:

```
fstream fin(path, ios::binary);
```

The other mistake is that you read the data as characters, not binary data. Also you don't need to one byte at a time in a loop:

```
fin.read(data, Block::BLOCK_SIZE);
```

I also suggest changing the `fstream` to `ifstream`, since you don't do any output on the file in the function.

The other mistake, as pointed out in another answer, is how you pass the `block` parameter.

Comment: thx for the suggestions. as for why i use loop one byte at a time to fill data is because fin.read() requires char* (the data here is byte*)

Comment: @bysreg My guess is that `byte` is just a typedef of `char`. There is no `byte` type in standard C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell just from the code, but it looks like you may be just storing the value of `data` in the `Block` constructor, rather than copying its contents into the member `data` array. `data` will go out of scope at the end of `getBlock()`, which will invalidate any attempts to read its memory.

Comment: The constructor is correctly copying the data, this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have to open fin stream in binary mode. Otherwise, '\r' characters will be lost (skipped).